# Prove the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n e^{-\mu x}}{x+\beta} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to prove this integral here:

[image]

Where Ei is the exponential integral. Unfortunately I don't have the right result yet, but I have other result that is not for this case, but I think it can help, due to the similar terms.

Knowing that:

[image]

and using $v=0$ and changing all variables to be similar to our case, we have:
[image]

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^n\mathrm{e}^{-\mu x}}{(x+\beta)}dx
$$
then we have
$$
(-1)^{n}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial \mu^n}\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\mu x}}{(x+\beta)}dx
$$
lets call $t = x+\beta$ we find
$$
(-1)^{n}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial \mu^n}\int_\beta^\infty\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\mu (t-\beta)}}{t}dt = (-1)^{n}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial \mu^n}\mathrm{e}^{\beta \mu}\int_\beta^\infty\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\mu t}}{t}dt
$$
let $\mu t = u$ leads to
$$
(-1)^{n}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial \mu^n}\mathrm{e}^{\beta \mu}\int_{\mu \beta}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-u}}{u} du
$$
we have
$$
\int_{\mu \beta}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-u}}{u} du = \mathrm{Ei}(-\beta \mu)
$$
SO i believe if you then take the derivative $n$-times with respect to $\mu$ will lead to what you wan i.e.
$$
(-1)^{n}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial \mu^n}\mathrm{e}^{\beta \mu}\mathrm{Ei}(-\beta \mu)
$$

Comment: will it work if n is real?

Comment: I assumed that $n$ is an integer given the summation you give in the original question. However, you can use fractional calculus, though I have to look into how that changes things (assumptions and so forth with the integral). Feel free to modify accordingly.